# "What's" and "what are"

Tags: plural-forms, grammatical-number, singular

Can I say "**What are there** to think about?" instead of "**What's there** to think about?"?

In this sentence, can I say *what's* even though I'm referring to *answers*, which is plural?

> "Hey, I've noticed that some of the answers on your answer sheet **are** wrong. Do you mind if I use **what's** on hers instead?"

Comment: Although colloquial I'd say that that just highlights it not being particularly good English - better would be 'those', or 'those that are', or 'the answers that are'. 'What's' here is contracting 'the answers what is', which is terrible grammar, it just sounds a little less awful contracted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: *what are there to think about* is wrong; *what's on hers* is right.

---

When *what* is used substantively, that is, as a noun, as opposed to an adjective, it can only be **singular** and have a singular verb if it is the subject. In *what's there to think about*, it is used substantively, so you can't replace *is* with *are*. You would have to turn it into an adjective to do so:

> What *things* are there to think about?

Here *what* functions like an adjective modifying the (substantive) noun *things*.

---

*What* can refer to something vague, like "everything on her answer sheet": when you use *what*, **you don't always need to refer back to a specific word**. In your clause *what's on hers instead*, the vague reference is perfectly fine. *What are* would not be correct.